# MySQL replication between main server and on-location laptops

Tags: mysql, synchronization, replication

We are a company that offers time tracking at all sorts of sport events. To store these timing results, we use laptops with a MySQL server, containing the timing data.

In the current situation we get a local copy of the master (the main server, running behind our website) just before we drive to the event, and submit these changes back to the master server after the event.

In the near future we would like implement live tracking on our website, and get user profile changes (users can change the time of their batch just before the batch starts) to the on-location machines.

An events exists of multiple batches (start times). A user subscribes to a certain batch, but sometimes when they are in traffic eg, they like to changes their batch to a later one.

So we need two way synchronisation, since data get updates on both our main server and our on-location machines.
On most events we have internet access. If we don't, I'd like to have the synchronisation working as soon as the connection gets online again.

I already found out about MySQL master-master replication. This looks pretty good, however I'm not feeling 100% satisfied.

Are there any suggestions how to setup such an environment? All suggestions are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Multi-Master replication is best in environments where the databases are always connected. This reduces the chance of conflicts. Multi-master replication does not have any automatic conflict resolution, which can lead to incorrect data if there is any latency between the two masters.

Multi-master replication is generally used to provide redundancy. If one master fails, all writes can failover to the other.

With multi-master replication, if you allow updates on both masters when there is latency between the servers (not connected or slow connection), you can have data conflicts, which can lead to incorrect or unexpected data.

Multi-master replication wasn't designed for offline distributed database synchronization, but it can be used in this situation if you have a strategy to avoid data conflicts.

To avoid conflicts entirely, allow updates to only one database at a time.

You could design the website to detect whether replication is active with the local database, and if it is, allow changes on the web site only, which then replicates to the local database.

If there is no Internet connection and replication, require users to update the data at the event, on the local database. Once you go back online or reestablish the connection, you can then replicate back to the website database.

Since data for different events won't conflict, this won't prevent your website from remaining in operation for upcoming events while you restrict updates on the website for ongoing events.

Regarding time tracking data, since that won't be updated on the website at all, you don't have to worry about conflicts. You can replicate that data to the website master any time you want.